# CMake: How to show headers in "Header files" in Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I have created a simple library project in C++ and added CMake file to automatically generate a Visual Studio project. My small project contains only 2 files:

```
include/
     testproject/
         testproject.h
src/
    testproject.cpp

CMakeLists.txt
```

Header file now in External Dependencies ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbQ2x.png)). How to display it in the section "Headers"? (or any other. Just not "External Dependencies")

CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

SET(PROJECTNAME testproject)

PROJECT(${PROJECTNAME})

FILE(GLOB MY_HEADERS "include/*.h")
FILE(GLOB MY_SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
ADD_LIBRARY(
    ${PROJECTNAME} STATIC
    ${MY_HEADERS} ${MY_SOURCES}
)
```

Note: If change dirs struct to

```
include/
     testproject.h
src/
    testproject.cpp

CMakeLists.txt
```

result will be like on a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujxCq.png). Header file in "Header files". But I need in previous project structure

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Pavlin How to display headers in the section "Header Files" of Visual Studio project? Header files is a part of my project it is not a External Dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GLOB_RECURSE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html):

> GLOB_RECURSE will generate a list similar to the regular GLOB, except it will traverse all the subdirectories of the matched directory and match the files. Subdirectories that are symlinks are only traversed if FOLLOW_SYMLINKS is given or cmake policy CMP0009 is not set to NEW. See cmake –help-policy CMP0009 for more information.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

SET(PROJECTNAME testproject)

PROJECT(${PROJECTNAME})

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE MY_HEADERS "include/*.h")
FILE(GLOB MY_SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
ADD_LIBRARY(
    ${PROJECTNAME} STATIC
    ${MY_HEADERS} ${MY_SOURCES}
)
```