# How can I get CMake to build my project while showing the include folder?

Tags: c++, cmake, ide, codelite

Say for example I have project hierarchy laid out like so...

```
CMAKE_PROJECT/
|
   |-build/
   |-include/
       |-Entity.hpp
       |-Scene.hpp
   |-src/
       |-Entity.cpp
       |-Scene.cpp
   CMakeLists.txt
```

How can I get my include files to show in my CodeLite project. It shows my `src` files perfectly fine, but the `include` folder is empty. Everything compiles and builds fine within the IDE, its just that the header includes are not visible in the project. What can I do to my `CMakeLists` to remedy this ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)

project(CMake_Project)
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "CMake_Project")

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
set (CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

set(SOURCES src/Entity.cpp 
            src/Scene.cpp)

include_directories(include)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../")

set(SFML_DIR "C:\\libs\\SFML-2.5.1\\lib\\cmake\\SFML")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS  audio network graphics window system REQUIRED)
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} sfml-audio sfml-network sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

I searched the internet and came across this,

[CMake: How to show headers in "Header files" in Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007099/cmake-how-to-show-headers-in-header-files-in-visual-studio-project)

and it works but `GLOB_RECURSE` is considered a bad practice. Is there an alternative ?

Comment: You could list the header files together with the source files for the [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) command? Or possibly use the [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html) command?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It worked!......Though I could have sworn I tried adding the headers to``add_executable`` before... Not quite sure why it worked now... This maybe out the scope of this question, but do you by any chance have any idea of why I have a ``src`` folder within my ``src`` folder. Same thing with my include folder. For example, ``src/src/<some_source_files>``. Its definitely not like that in my project hierarchy. Is it something CMake is causing ?

Comment: It might have to do with the Codelite IDE setup? I don't know, as I don't really use it myself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It appears to be IDE related, because when I built the source for another IDE the file structure is totally different. You can post your first comment as the answer and I'll gladly accept it

Comment: There is a very similar question with several answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13703647/3987854).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to also include header files in a project is to also list them in the [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) command.

Perhaps something like

```
set(SOURCES src/Entity.cpp 
            src/Scene.cpp)

set(HEADERS include/Entity.hpp 
            include/Scene.hpp)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```